# How to use .flat() in an angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to use `flat()` in my Angular ts file. When I run the project it gives an error: `[question.determinativeTerms].flat` is not a function!
I installed it:

`npm install --save array.prototype.flat`

```
function matchUserInputToDeterminativePhrases(
    faqs: Question[],
    searchPhrase: string
): Question[] {
    return faqs.reduce((matches, question) => {
        let foundMatch = false;
        [question.determinativeTerms].flat().forEach(term => {
            if (
                !foundMatch &&
                searchPhrase &&
                searchPhrase
                .toLowerCase()
                .search(new RegExp(`\\b${term.toLowerCase()}`)) !== -1
            ) {
                foundMatch = true;
                matches.push(question);
            }
        });
        return matches.reverse();
    }, []);
}
```

Comment: you npm installed it, but did you import it anywhere?

Comment: yes, I tried, import flat from 'array.prototype.flat'; at the component in which I'm using the flat() method and in the main.ts as well!

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to npm install the package, you need to import and use it. Looking at the [documentation for array.prototype.flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array.prototype.flat), it appears that if you want to add the function onto the array prototype, you need to do the following somewhere in your app:

```
import flat from 'array.prototype.flat';
flat.shim();
```

Answer (score 0):

As of angular 11 and thx to [typescript 3.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html) you can now directly use the `flat()` method inside angular with the following configuration in your `tsconfig.json` file.

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
}
```

[for further read](https://angular.io/guide/migration-update-module-and-target-compiler-options)